# Should one unit test persistence in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, tdd

We're doing a rails 3.2.1 project with RSpec 2.  My question is, should i be testing the basic persistence of each of my activerecord models?  I used to do this in my C# / NHibernate days, to ensure the correct tables/mappings were there.

So if i have a customer with name, address and phone fields, I might write an rspec like this:

```
describe Customer do
    it "saves & retrieves its fields to and from the db"

    c = Customer.new
    c.name = "Bob Smith"
    c.address = "123 some street"
    c.phone = "555-555-5555"
    or = Order.new
    c.orders << or

    c.save

    found = Customer.find(c.id)
    found.should_not be(c)
    found.name.should == c.name
    found.address.should == c.address
    found.phone.should == c.phone
    found.orders.count.should == 1
    found.orders[0].id.should == or.id

    end
end
```

Is this "best practice" or common in the ruby/rails/rspec world?  I should also note that the point is not to test what rails is doing natively, but instead test that the correct fields and relationships are setup in the db and models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You shouldn't be **unit** testing the persistence. A unit test validates the unit works in isolation, and you should only test *your* code. The persistence functionality is a part of Rails, and since it is not your code, you shouldn't write unit tests for it.

You *could* be interested in testing the **mappings**, but not in a unit test. You would write an **integration** test for that. An integration test would test your module, integrating with another part of the system, perhaps all the way to the database. Running those tests would validate that your module works with the database, i.e. the **mappings** are good.

In short - you don't test persistence in **unit** tests; you test them in **integration** tests.

Comment: I guess i'm using the wrong terminology.  I had forgotten the difference between unit tests and integration test.  So in your opinion, is it a good idea to create integration tests for these types of mappings in rails?  Is it common?

Comment: I must confess that I'm not very familiar with Rails, as I have most of my experience in the .net framework, but yes, it is **very** common to test the persistence layer with integration tests. Besides, technically, any persistence layer testing would be integration tests, and any SAT tests would include persistence validations.

Comment: +1 for explaining when it is appropriate, even if it's not appropriate in the situation the OP is describing.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't believe it is a best practice to do this sort of lower level testing as the majority of these tests would be built into to the testing for Rails and the ORM you are using.

However, if you are overriding any methods or performing complex association logic in your models it'd be best to have your own tests.